# Is it possible to customize the left bottom button in numberpad on iOS6/7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, numpad

The default left bottom button is +*# in NumberPad keyboard, but I want the user TO see the NumberPad by default and can click a button to switch to the ASCII keyboard. So is it a way to customize the +*# button in iOS6/7?

Comment: Or is it possible to switch between number input view and letters input view of UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable with code? I want to show the number input view by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an custom view as per your requirement and assign it to textfield input accessory view.

This [link](https://github.com/lnafziger/Numberpad) may help.